# External dependencies, Haskell, stack: should I modify something or 'import' suppose to be sufficient?

Tags: haskell, dependency-management, haskell-stack

I am pretty new to Haskell as well as stack.

```
import Data.Set
import Data.Stack
```

The statements above trigger compilation error: `Could not find module 'Data.Set'. Perhaps you meant 'Data.Int'`. I tried to google and found nothing similar.

Hence, my question is: do I need to specify external dependencies manually or just my `stack build` command somewhy fails to grab appropriate modules from somewhat cache or repository?

In case I have to specify my dependencies manually, should I prefer `.cabal` or `.yaml`? What's the correct way to deal with versioning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [Do] I need to specify external dependencies manually [...]?

Yes.

Since you are using Stack, it is easy to specify the dependent packages you import in your code. Depend on your Stack version, the default configuration might be a little bit different:

1. If you created your project with the latest version of Stack, you will see `package.yaml` in the root of your project (`hpack` is used in this case to specify the configurations). You need to add package dependencies there, e.g., `containers` for `Data.Set`. Here's an example of a dependencies section in one of my projects:

   ```
   dependencies:
   - base >= 4.7 && < 5
   - containers
   - time
   - network
   - bytestring
   ```
2. If you are using an older version of `stack` and do not see `package.yaml`, you need to edit `your-project-name.cabal` to add the dependencies. Here's the complete document telling you how to do it: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#adding-dependencies

Personally, I prefer the new system with `hpack` (`package.yaml`). Basically, it is simpler, and it saves you time declaring all modules you have (not about dependency). If you have `package.yaml`, do not edit `.cabal`, which is automatically generated by `hpack`.